# What type of filler to replace a gasket but not permanently?

Tags: adhesive, epoxy

I have a connection that has a custom-shaped hard plastic gasket with strong adhesive to hold the two sides together. The gasket is meant to fill the gap between the two pieces and the adhesive bonds them together.

I have to do repair on this connection which requires that the gasket be completely removed from both ends which damages it in the process and it cannot be reused.

Is there some form of soft silicone or other kind of adhesive that I can use to fill this void that is strong enough to bind the two ends but not permanently in case I need to remove it again? I can't use a normal glue because it flows too easily and I don't want to use epoxy because I'm afraid that I won't be able to separate the parts again.

Comment: Gasket material is sold (google or search amazon) and you can cut your own.  You probably need to provide more info tho for better answers. Example missing info: hot? cold?, water, gas, air?  Pressure?

Answer (score 1):

Permatex markets a variety of [gasket sealants,](https://www.permatex.com/product-category/gasketing/gasket-sealants/) depending on exactly what you're sealing. Of particular note in this situation are the various High Tack branded ones which combine gasket and adhesive. It's more likely you'll find them in an automotive parts dealer than at the hardware store.

Comment: I agree there are different types of rtv that may do this job, I stock neoprene gaskets for some equipment that needs sealing and different thickness of high pressure "paper type" gaskets when needed and supplement a thin coat of rtv works great.

Comment: Which ones of these sealants will dry? Ideally I'd like something that turns into a soft rubber or something with a silicone feel to it.